# Simply Supported beam with multiple point loads and distributed load

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, beam, finite-element-method

How can I solve this problem using FEM (longhand calculation)? I want to find deflections at each load point. This is not a homework problem. This is related to a project that I and my brother is doing for the conveyor. The distributed load is conveyor and point loads are some features that we are trying to add to it. I tried to solve this by Integrating moment function but if I try to add/remove point load from this, I have to do that integration part again and in some cases, the distributed by leg supports instead of any beam. 
I was thinking this problem can be generalized through FEA.

1) I want to find deflection at each node point (where the loads are) and maximum deflection

2) I tried to solve this by double integration method but that method will only be specific to this beam that is why I thought of the FEM

3) In this example, conveyor is resting on the beam that is the distributed load and when conveyor is supported by leg supports, there is no need for calculation as they are standard

4) I do not have FEA software package.

$E=300\times10^6\text{ psi}=2068\ GPa\quad,\quad I=500\text{ in}^4=2.08\times10^{-4}\text{ m}^4$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, what do you mean by "solve this problem"? Do you want the deflection? If so, do you want the deflection equation or just the maximum deflection? Also, what do you mean by "the distributed by leg supports instead of any beam"? And does the solution actually have to be by FEM, or is that just how you thought to solve it? Please [edit] your question with this additional information.

Comment: do you have a FEM package, do you know how to use it?  Its really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited my question answering all questions, please review it. Thank you.

Comment: Wait, what are you designing here? The conveyor or the beam? Which is supporting which? I assume the beam is supporting the conveyor, but then you say the "conveyor is resting on the beam that is the distributed load". So, the beam is the distributed load? Do you simply mean that the beam's self-weight is the distributed load which the beam itself needs to withstand? Or that the beam is actually just a load being supported by something else (the conveyor?), and what we're designing is actually that something-else?

Comment: The conveyor is supported by the beam. We are designing beam. Distributed load(6lb/in) that is shown is coming from the conveyor

Comment: google online beam calculator, https://beamguru.com/online/beam-calculator/ looks promising